# Writing a book chapter with given .sty file

Tags: packages

I am totally new to writing with Latex or Tex. I have only written one article before using LyX editor. At that time I had a predefined template present in LyX.
This time I am trying to write a chapter for Wiley and have been given a .sty file only. LyX does not have any in-built template for Wiley. What can I do to write in LYX with the format I am asked to write?
The files supplied to me can be found here: [Wiley Latex Template](https://authorservices.wiley.com/author-resources/book-authors/prepare-your-manuscript/wiley-latex-template.html)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. *If you wish to use the Wiley LaTeX template, please discuss first with your Wiley contact.


Note: The template will not be used for the presentation of the final page layout.* Just deliver the content, that is what they are interested in.

Comment: And consider reading an introduction to LaTeX, which is required to use LyX properly.

Comment: @Johannes_B The official mail I received, asked me to use it and deliver the chapter in .tex format. I have been trying to write using Latex coding but images and tables are not positioned correctly. I am in total confusion as I am just learning to write using LyX editor and had no previous experience with writing a paper in Latex.

Comment: Deliver as a tex file, not a lyx file. If you export from LyX, you will get some strange stuff. Don't care about where the images are placed. Wiley will do that for you for the book.

Comment: @Johannes_B Ok, thank you.